# NextJS - keep header and footer on page

Tags: ajax, next.js

I am wondering is their anyway to have it so that when a navigation menu is clicked that it only changes the  `<main className={styles.main}>` content if Ajax allowed?

I know with ReactJS I can do this - but no matter how many documents I read I can't figure it out with NextJS.

currently I have pre-loading / prefetch but the header and footer disappear.

in my index.js my links look like this.

```
 <Link href="/news" prefetch className={styles.card}>
            <a>news.</a>
 </Link>
```

full index.js code

```
<div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.drn1.com.au/img/websitepromo.jpg"></meta>
      </Head>
      
     
    


      <main className={styles.main}>
    
        <div className={styles.grid}>
        <Link href="/news" prefetch className={styles.card}>
            
            <a>news.</a>
          </Link>

          
         
        </div>
      </main>

      <footer className={styles.footer}>
        <a
          href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Powered by{' '}
          <span className={styles.logo}>
            <Image src="/vercel.svg" alt="Vercel Logo" width={72} height={16} />
          </span>
        </a>
      </footer>
    </div>
```

I would like only the  `<main className={styles.main}>` area to reload not the full page.

Any ideas